# My perfect shopping cart class

Tags: php, e-commerce

Here is my shopping cart class! I want it to be perfect and never to have to implement it.

What improvements would you do?

### New : IComparable

```
interface IComparable
{
    public function equals($object);
}
```

### New : ICartItem

```
interface ICartItem extends IComparable
{
    public function setQuantity($quantity);
    public function getQuantity();
}
```

### New : ICart

```
interface ICart
{
    public function add(ICartItem $item);
    public function remove(ICartItem $item);
    public function getQuantity(ICartItem $item);
    public function setQuantity(ICartItem $item, $quantity);
    public function isEmpty();
    public function getItems();
    public function clear();
}
```

### New : Cart

```
class SessionCart implements ICart
{
    const IDENTIFIER = '_CART_';
    protected $items;

    public function __construct(&$container = null)
    {
        if (is_null($container)) {
            if (session_id() == '') {
                session_start();
            }
            if (!isset($_SESSION[self::IDENTIFIER])) {
                $_SESSION[self::IDENTIFIER] = array();
            }
            $container = & $_SESSION[self::IDENTIFIER];
        }
        $this->items = & $container;
    }

    public function add(ICartItem $item)
    {
        $index = $this->getIndexOfItem($item);

        if ($index == -1) {
            $this->items[] = $item;

        } else {
            $item = $this->items[$index];
            $item->setQuantity($item->getQuantity() + 1);
        }

        return $item->getQuantity();
    }

    public function remove(ICartItem $item)
    {
        $index = $this->getIndexOfItem($item);

        if ($index == -1) {
            throw new Exception('The item isn\'t inside the cart.');
        }

        $item = $this->items[$index];

        $quantity = $item->getQuantity() - 1;

        if ($quantity > 0) {
            $item->setQuantity($quantity);

        } else {
            unset($this->items[$index]);
        }
        return $quantity;
    }

    public function getQuantity(ICartItem $item)
    {
        $index = $this->getIndexOfItem($item);

        if ($index == -1) {
            return 0;

        } else {
            return $this->items[$index]->getQuantity();
        }
    }

    public function setQuantity(ICartItem $item, $quantity)
    {
        if (($quantity = (int)$quantity) < 1) {
            throw new Exception('A positive quantity is required.');
        }

        $index = $this->getIndexOfItem($item);

        if ($index == -1) {
            $item->setQuantity($quantity);
            $this->items[] = $item;

        } else {
            $item = $this->items[$index];
            $item->setQuantity($quantity);
        }

        return $item->getQuantity();
    }

    public function isEmpty()
    {
        return empty($this->items);
    }

    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }

    public function clear()
    {
        $this->items = array();
    }

    private function getIndexOfItem(ICartItem $item)
    {
        foreach ($this->items as $key => $value) {
            if ($item->equals($value)) {
                return $key;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### General

You should reconsider the naming of some methods. For example,

```
interface IComparable
{
    public function equals($obj);
}
```

is more clear about what it really does (comments are omitted to save space; of course, proper DocBlock comments should always be included with your code). This way, you can easily add other methods like `isLessThan`, `isGreaterOrEqual`, and so on. A method named `compareTo` as in

```
$a->compareTo($b)
```

I'd expect to be a valid callback for `usort`, thus returning -1 on `$a < $b`, 0 on `$a == $b`, or 1 on `$a > $b`.

### Cart

One day, you might want to store your cart items in a database, so using `$_SESSION` directly is not optimal. I'd define a cart interface:

```
interface ICart
{
    public function add(IComparable $obj);
    public function remove(IComparable $obj);
    public function getQuantity(IComparable $obj);
    public function setQuantity(IComparable $obj, $qty);
    public function isEmpty();
    public function getAll();
    public function clear();
}

class Cart implements ICart
{
    const IDENTIFIER = '_CART_';
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(&$container = null)
    {
        if (is_null($container)) {
            if (session_id() == '') {
                session_start();
            }
            if (!isset($_SESSION[self::IDENTIFIER])) {
                $_SESSION[self::IDENTIFIER] = array();
            }
            $container = &$_SESSION[self::IDENTIFIER];
        }
        $this->container = &$container;
    }
}
```

With this approach, you can always build other cart implementations, like a database-aware one. The `Cart` class can be provided with an array, which will be used to store the data. If you want, you can pass in the `$_SESSION` superglobal directly, or use any other array. If omitted, a kind of namespace within the session variables (`self::IDENTIFIER`, `'_CART_'`) is used to store the data.

Since the session - if needed - is started within the constructor, you can rely on its existence in the subsequent methods. BTW: the existence of the `$_SESSION` array does not guarantee that a session has been started! Use `session_id()` to check that instead.)

#### Internal Data Structure

Since your data array can be accessed from outside the cart, the current data structure is prone to get out of sync. It is more robust to swap the indices. Then you can replace `getIndex()` with `getEntry()`, which makes the handling much easier.

```
class Cart implements ICart
{
    ... // see above

    public function add(IComparable $obj)
    {
        $entry = &$this->getEntry($obj);
        $entry['quantity']++;

        return $entry['quantity'];
    }

    public function remove(IComparable $obj)
    {
        $entry = &$this->getEntry($obj);
        $entry['quantity'] = max(0, --$entry['quantity']);

        return $entry['quantity'];
    }

    public function getQuantity(IComparable $obj)
    {
        $entry = &$this->getEntry($obj);
        return $entry['quantity'];
    }

    public function setQuantity(IComparable $obj, $qty)
    {
        $entry = &$this->getEntry($obj);
        if ($entry['quantity'] > 0) {
            $entry['quantity'] = (int) $qty;
        }
        return $entry['quantity'];
    }

    public function isEmpty()
    {
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($this->container as $entry) {
            $total += $entry['quantity'];
        }
        return $total <= 0;
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        $cart = array();
        foreach ($this->container as $entry) {
            if ($entry['quantity'] > 0) {
                $cart[] = $entry;
            }
        }
        return $cart;
    }

    public function clear()
    {
        $this->container = array();
    }

    private function &getEntry(IComparable $obj)
    {
        foreach ($this->container as &$entry) {
            if ($obj->equals($entry['item'])) {
                return $entry;
            }
        }
        $entry = array(
            'item' => $obj,
            'quantity' => 0
        );
        $this->container[] = &$entry;
        return $entry;
    }
}
```

As you can see, all methods (excl. `isEmpty()`) become much simpler.

Comment: Only one question : The shopping cart is it a singleton? If so, the variable `container` should it not be static?

Comment: There is no reason for the cart to be a singleton (singleton is an Antipattern). On the other hand, the `container` property holds a *reference* to the cart data, so any cart provided with the same storage container will have identical data.

Comment: For example, should I call the cart this way: `(new Cart())->clear()`?

Comment: Why you don't use `array_sum()` for the isEmpty() function? And I don't understand `$this->container[] = &$entry;`. Why you ecrase the table?

Comment: To use the cart, you instantiate it: `$myCart = new Cart;`. Then you can use it's methods: `$myCart->clear();`. Static methods are avoided, because they hamper testing. -- array_sum is not used, because the values are not in the same array (each item is again an array within the main array).

Comment: `$this->container[] = &$entry;` does not erase the array, but adds a reference to the new entry.

Comment: Sorry to insist, but I don't understand. Can you explain to me ... Why don't you have to specify the index of the array.

Comment: Read this from the PHP manual: php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying. It'll tell you.

Comment: I do not know why, but I can not increment the quantity of an item. If I follow step by step the execution, I realize that this is the code that does not work: `$entry['quantity']++;` and `$entry['quantity']--;`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8579/discussion-between-nibra-and-hugo-lapointe-di-giacomo)

Answer (score 5):

### Based on @nibra's solution

- Same `ICompareable` interface.
- Same `ICart` interface but derived from `IteratorAggregate`.

  ```
  interface ICart extends IteratorAggregate {}
  ```

### `CartItem` class

- Storing an item.
- Storing the quantity if the item.

```
final class CartItem {

    private $_item;
    private $_quantity;

    public function __construct(IComparable $item, $quantity = 1) {
        $quantity = (int)$quantity;
        if ($quantity < 1) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid quantity");
        }

        $this->_item = $item;
        $this->_quantity = $quantity;
    }

    public function GetQuantity() {
        return $this->_quantity;
    }

    public function GetItem() {
        return $this->_item;
    }
}
```

### Changed internal behavior

- `Cart` isn't the best name for this kind of implementation because it's not reflecting anything about the implementation, so call it `SessionCart`.
- `session_start();` doesn't belong here because starting the session isn't the responsibility of this class; if we wan't to ensure that the session has been started we need another abstraction above the `$_SESSION` array.
- `$_SESSION` as storage backend implies some kind of singleton behavior so we need to handle multiple instance problem with the `SessionCart` class but this also not the responsibility of `SessionCart` class because it depends on the framework.
- `&` operator is bad because it can mess up our code and it really hurts performance; in PHP 5 and above we never really need to use it, see `CartItem` class.
- quantity: 0; why would we store items with the quantity of 0? If the quantity is 0 then we don't have any item of that type so remove it.

```
class SessionCart implements ICart {
    protected $container;

    public function __construct($storageIndex = "_CART_") {
        if (isset($_SESSION[$storageIndex])) {
            throw new Exception($storageIndex . " exists in SESSION array");
        }

        $_SESSION[$storageIndex] = $this;
    }

    public function add(IComparable $obj, $quantity) {
        $quantity = (int)$quantity;

        if ($quantity < 1) {
            //throw exception?
            return 0;
        }

        $index = $this->getIndexOfEntry($obj, $quantity);

        if ($index == -1) {
            $this->container[] = new CartItem($obj);
            return 1;
        } 

        $this->container[$index] = new CartItem($obj, $this->container[$index]->GetQuantity() + $quantity);
        return $this->container[$index]->GetQuantity();
    }

    public function remove(IComparable $obj) {
        $index = $this->getIndexOfEntry($obj);
        unset($this->container[$index]);
    }

    public function getQuantity(IComparable $obj) {
        $index = $this->getIndexOfEntry($obj);
        return $index == -1 ? 0 : $this->container[$index]->GetQuantity();
    }

    public function setQuantity(IComparable $obj, $qty) {
        $qty = (int)$qty;

        if ($qty < 1) {
            $this->remove($obj);
            return;
        }

        $index = $this->getIndexOfEntry($obj);

        if ($index == -1) {
            $this->container[] = new CartItem($obj, $qty);
        } else {
            $this->container[$index] = new CartItem($obj, $qty);
        }
    }

    public function isEmpty() {
        return empty($this->container);
    }

    public function getAll() {
        return new SplFixedArray($this->container);
    }

    public function clear() {
        $this->container = array();
    }

    private function getIndexOfEntry(IComparable $obj) {
        foreach ($this->container as $key => $entry) {
            if ($obj->equals($entry->GetItem())) {
                return $key;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public function getIterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->container);
    }

}
```

### Problem

The code above still depends on `$_SESSION` array which is bad (hard dependency on a global variable is bad and global variables are always bad) because anyone can modify it's content. I have mentioned another abstraction above the `$_SESSION` array in the previous section and I think it's a must have to do scenario if we want a perfect implementation of a session based cart.

Comment: I like your way of thinking. Would it be a good idea to define the class CartItem inside SessionCart? According, it is the only class that will use it.

Comment: Why you return the index rather than the entry!?

Comment: Becouse the entry (CartItem) is immutable therefore you cannot change the item or the quantity inside it. Yes we can create a class which isn't immutable and we can return the entry it self but then for example the delete would be a little more complicated but yes we can create one method to return an entry and one method to return the index of an entry (IComparable) it's up to you.

Answer (score 3):

I would reccomend to use `if(session_id() == ''){ //do }` instead of `if(!isset($_SESSION)) { // do}` because $_SESSION can be set while the session is closed.